# Обращение из подзапроса к столбцам внешнего запроса SQL

Tags: sql, рекурсия

Писал запрос, обратился за помощью к chatGPT и он выдал такой. И этот код работает. Проверил в питоне, через pandasql запустил запрос и он сработал. Но вот ни в одном субд SQL он не сработал, т.к. в нем из внутри ПОДЗАПРОСА с таблицей t2 в блоке WHERE обращаются к столбцам из таблица t1, которая находится во внешнем запросе. Т.е. обращается к еще не созданной таблице. Такое конечно должно привести к ошибке, но я не понял почему pandasql выполнил этот запрос и дал правильную таблицу. Может кто объяснить?

```
    SELECT manager_name,
        manager_id,
        sal,
        vsp_name,
        rank,
        CASE 
        WHEN sal = MAX(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY vsp_name) THEN -1
        ELSE (
            SELECT t2.manager_name
            FROM df AS t2
            WHERE t2.vsp_name = t1.vsp_name
                AND t2.rank = t1.rank - 1
                AND (
                    t2.sal > t1.sal
                    OR (t2.sal = t1.sal AND t2.manager_id > t1.manager_id)
                )
            ORDER BY t2.sal DESC, t2.manager_id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        END as bigger_sal_name
FROM df as t1
ORDER BY vsp_name, sal DESC
```

Comment: Это коррелированный подзапрос. Причём он коррелирован с ближайшим уровнем. То есть синтаксически запрос абсолютно верен. Если не считать одной проблемы - слово `rank` является ключевым, а в некоторых диалектах и зарезервированным, и это может привести к ошибке выполнения запроса. Рекомендую переименовать поле или по крайней мере квотировать его имя в тексте запроса.

Comment: *Т.е. обращается к еще не созданной таблице.* С чего бы? Подзапрос обращается к полям текущей записи из статической таблицы `df as t1`, которая является источником данных основного запроса. И что тут имеется в виду под словами "не созданной" - непонятно.

Comment: Ну тут мы имеем что параллельно рассчитываются два разных manager_id из таблиц t1 и t2 и сравниваются между собой. Я такое в Sql вижу впервые, тк он требователен к последовательной линейности. Повторяю в запросах при выполнении в настоящих субд sql он выдал ошибки с формулировками типа "такого столбца еще не существует", "вы пытаетесь сравнить чтото что требует предварительной группировки", и только pandasql все посчитал. И не понял почему какой то эмулятор нарушает правила оригинальной субд

Comment: *он требователен к последовательной линейности* Кто Вам  сказал такую глупость? *Повторяю в запросах при выполнении в настоящих субд sql он выдал ошибки с формулировками типа "такого столбца еще не существует"* Этот запрос и аналогичный запрос - это разные вещи. *не понял почему какой то эмулятор нарушает правила* Давайте разговаривать предметно. Выкладывайте ссылку на online fiddle с проблемой - тогда будет о чём говорить.